# Keras LSTM predict with sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, tensorflow2.0

I made a Keras LSTM Model. But my problem is that with my input_shape [800, 200, 48] i predict a output with the shape [800, 200, 48].

I only need to predict the 800x48 labels without any sequences.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4BqL.png)

Input: 800 Samples, 200 time_steps, 48 features per time_step

Needed Output is: 800 Samples, 48 features per time_step

I hope someone have a solution for this!

Code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout


model = Sequential()
        

def addInputLayer(units, shape, dropout):
    model.add(LSTM(input_shape=shape, units=units, use_bias=True, unit_forget_bias=True, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
        
        
def addHiddenLayer(anz, units, dropout):
    for i in range(anz):
        model.add(LSTM(units=units, use_bias=True, unit_forget_bias=True, return_sequences=True))
        model.add(Dropout(dropout))
            
            
def addOutputLayer(units):
    model.add(Dense(units=units))
    
    
def compLstm(optimizer, loss_function):
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss_function)
    
    
def konfigure(feature, label, epochs, validationFeature, validationLabel, batch_size):
    history = model.fit(feature, label, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(validationFeature, validationLabel), batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2)
    return history


def predict(test):
    predictions = model.predict(test)
    return predictions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, the parameter `return_sequences` of your last `LSTM` layer should be `False`. Since you're using a loop, try something like this. Here, `return_sequences` will be `True` for all except the last loop iteration.

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

anz = 8

for i in range(anz):
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=200, return_sequences=i != anz - 1))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(48, activation='softmax'))

model.build(input_shape=(None, 200, 48))

model.summary()
```

```
Model: "sequential_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_38 (LSTM)               (None, 200, 200)          199200    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_39 (LSTM)               (None, 200, 200)          320800    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_40 (LSTM)               (None, 200, 200)          320800    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_41 (LSTM)               (None, 200, 200)          320800    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_42 (LSTM)               (None, 200, 200)          320800    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_43 (LSTM)               (None, 200, 200)          320800    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_44 (LSTM)               (None, 200, 200)          320800    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_45 (LSTM)               (None, 200)               320800    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 48)                9648      
=================================================================
Total params: 2,454,448
Trainable params: 2,454,448
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```